# Single sign-on Office 365 and an ASP.Net web application

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, single-sign-on

I want to implement single sign-on on `Office 365` with an `ASP.Net web application`.

For example, if a user is logged in to `Office 365` and then he opens the web application in the same session, then the browser should not ask for credential again.
My `Asp.Net web application` is using form based authentication.

Please help.

Comment: Hi @Noman, do you have same accounts on office 365 and your Asp.Net web application?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have azure AD? If yes you may consider using WIF (Windows identity foundation) for authentication making use of ASP.Net membership and Azure STS.

Please refer this link, http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/single-sign-on

Comment: No, we don't have Azure AD.

Comment: Hi @Sriram, can we sync Azure AD with on-premise AD?

Comment: @MAK **Yes**, we can sync azure AD with on premise AD, please refer this link to know more [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/05/14/step-by-step-syncing-on-premise-ad-with-azure-active-directory.aspx)

Comment: @Sriram, Thanks. can we use OAuth or some other method similar to OAuth? I think 'Noman' is using database for asp.net authentication. If anyone having any idea?